# CSS rgba Background Color Validation

Tags: css, background-color

I found a weird CSS validation result: when `rgba()` is used to `background`, it does not validate, however, the workaround is `rgba()` for `background-color`. Why that rule exists? Is it a validator's bug?

Try to validate the following [there](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options), and you can see the result:

```
div {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

and

```
div {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Sure looks like a validator bug to me. You might want to report it to www-validator-css@w3.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's validator's bug. For example, HSL color space is rejected too

```
.accepted {
   background-color: hsl(1, 1%, 1%);
}

.rejected {
   background: hsl(1, 1%, 1%);
}
```